# Can I interpret the signs of coefficients in a VAR model?

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, model, vector-autoregression

I estimated a VAR-model. I checked the time series for stationarity and after estimating the model the residuals and all is fine.

I know that it makes no sense to directly interpret the coefficients but I wondered if it is eligible to interpret the signs of the coefficients? E.g. The second lag is significant and seems to have a negative influence on y. ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That's why people typically look at impulse responses, which are easier to interpret.

Comment: To the extent that you cannot directly interpret the coefficient, the same likely holds for its sign as well.